# Swiftui decodable, Printing multiple searches

Tags: swiftui, decodable

So in Swiftui, I'm trying to output multiple multiple of post.hints. It's a part of a large hierarchy. "results" itself is a list and I'm trying to make result = every single option rather than just one. What's the most efficient way to do that?

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        if let posts = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!) {
            results = [posts.hints[10].food]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I could just make a for loop and append each one.

```
if let posts = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!) {
//            results = [posts.hints[10].food]
            for i in posts.hints {
                results.append(i.food)
            }
            }
```

Comment: You asked about efficiency, so your answer should indicate if the proposed solution is indeed efficient.

Comment: I apologize, I do believe in my limited understanding that this is an efficient way. May not be the most efficient though.